# Update manually installed modules

Tags: 8, commerce, composer

I have installed Drupal Commerce 2 through composer as mentioned in

https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation

after that, I have installed a few modules and a Barrio (Theme) directly through drupal admin interface.

Can I still update them through composer?

I have tried to update with `~/composer.phar update drupal/block_class --with-dependencies`, but I am getting the following output.

> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
>   Package "drupal/block_class" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
>   Loading composer repositor
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files
>   DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I still update them through composer?

No, Composer can only manage packages that have been installed through Composer.

You could always add it to the `"require"` section of your existing composer.json (manually or by executing `composer require`), then Composer will know about it.